# On clicking button to run function in Electron program, page contents are cleared and function does not run

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a very strange error. When I click a button to run a function `open()` the function does not run (`console.log` does not log anything). However, in Developer Tools, when I go to console and run `open()`, it seems to run perfectly fine.

`open()` is used to open a file open dialog.

Here is the button:

```
<button class="w3-button" id="openButton" onclick="open();">Open</button>
```

Here is `open()` in `scripts.js` (referenced by the HTML file):

```
//open file
function open() {
  ipcRenderer.send('openFile', {});
  console.log("wtf?");
  //judging by absence of above statement on button click, this is probably a HTML problem...?
}
```

Here is the function that is supposed to open the dialog in `main.js`:

```
ipcMain.on('openFile', function () {
  //show open dialog
  dialog.showOpenDialog({
    defaultPath: '~/',
    filters: [
      {name: 'Text Files', extensions: ['txt']},
      {name: 'All Files', extensions: ['*']}
    ]
  }, function() {
    console.log("wtf?");
    //open the file
    fs.readFile();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the first place is that `open` is a [reserved name](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)

To resolve your problem you either

1. Rename the function and everything works as is or
2. Add `open` as a property of your button

```js
document.getElementById('openButton').open = () => {
  ipcRenderer.send('openFile', {})
}
```

and call that in the callback

```
<button class="w3-button" id="openButton" onclick="this.open()">Open</button>
```

3. Don't use name for listener

```js
document.getElementById('openButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  ipcRenderer.send('openFile', {})
}
```

---

*Sorry for re-working the whole answer. Adding `open` to `document` was an ugly workaround*

Comment: Thanks! First option worked for me. May I know how exactly it works?

Comment: Just discovered that the actual name was the problem in the first place. Updated my answer! ;)

Comment: and re-defining `document.open` is not a nice way to go

Comment: Thanks for the help!